# WMI queries random access denied

Tags: powershell, wmi

Why does the `Win32_Service` WMI query randomly fail with deny access to my WMI Queries.

I'm running a `Win32_Service` WMI query daily against several different domains. Today I've noticed that the query failed in one DOMAIN because it was denied access.  When I run the queries in a loop they fail at times that seem random to me.  It will run successfully, fail once or twice and then run successfully again. So far I have only seen this occur in one of the domains I am checking.

This is the error message

```
Friday, December 09, 2016 2:33:26 PM
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At C:\junk\Untitled2.ps1:23 char:22
+     $Service_Data =  Get-WmiObject `
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

This is the template for what I'm running

```
$loopDelay = 60
$userName  = 'Domain1\LocalAdmin'
$pwd       = 'Password'

$Sec_Pwd   = $pwd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds     = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $Sec_Pwd

$Servers   = @()
$Servers  += "Server1.Domain1.org"
$Servers  += "Server2.Domain1.org"
$Servers  += "Server3.Domain1.org"
$Servers  += "Server4.Domain1.org"

while (1 -eq 1)
{
    Get-Date
    $Service_Data = Get-WmiObject -Credential $creds -ComputerName $Servers Win32_Service |
                    where {$_.Name -eq "JunkTest"} |
                    select SystemName, State, Status
    $Service_Data | Format-Table
    "<Ctrl><C> to quit"
    sleep 60
}
```

Comment: `$pwd` is an [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Automatic_Variables). Do not manually assign values to those.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: for whatever reason - these queries only failed randomly in Domain1 when I was running the script from another Domain.   I moved my server into Domain1 and was glad to see the WMI queries are running again. I'm still not sure why Domain1 was failing randomly from DomainX.  Is this issue possible due to the domain controllers in domain1 ?